# Chrome Extension : Cross Origin $.Post Request

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access posterous API , to POST some content to site via google chrome extension ( and otherwise ) .

Since it's a public API , so I expect it to allow everyone to post , but for some reason , it does'nt allow to post .

However everytime I get error .

Same error comes when I access it from browsers

**here's the error when accessed via browser**

http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

**here's the error when accessed via chrome extension**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://posterous.com/api/2/users/me/sites/primary/posts?api_token=vxgufysnzlDwmEtkbDbzHtxxBADsEFGr&email=***@gmail.com&password=***. Origin chrome-extension://maabelkjnhafpphacjecmcnkkmjndjgl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

**Here's the code :**

```
$.ajax({
        //type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://posterous.com/api/2/users/me/sites/primary/posts?api_token=vxgufysnzlDwmEtkbDbzHtxxBADsEFGr&email=shahid1376@gmail.com&password=WHY_DID_YOU_PUT_YOUR_REAL_PASS',
      // url:'http://posterous.com/api/2/users/me/sites/primary/posts/public',
       type : 'POST',

        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: "{'title': 'test posterous'}",
        contentType:'text/plain',
        success:function result(data) {
                alert("Call completed successfully"); 
        }
```

Comment: you didn't actually post your password in the code above did you??

Comment: Edited. ._O You're lucky that didn't get into the wrong hands.

Comment: Are you running this in a background page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `manifest.json` file should have the two domains you're looking to use in the permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*.posterous.com/",
    "http://localhost/"
]
```

For what it's worth, I wouldn't include `localhost` in your `permissions`; rather, use the domain you plan to use in production and then use a `hosts` line to redirect the domain to your own server. This will let you develop on your own server but won't force your users to allow permissions on `localhost` which they might not expect.

Comment: Exactly. From Google Code: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions "Required if the extension wants to interact with the code running on pages. Many extension capabilities, such as cross-origin XMLHttpRequests, programmatically injected content scripts, and the cookies API require host permissions. For details on the syntax, see Match Patterns."

Comment: Nexxeus thanks for replacing the original pass , It skipped out of my mind :)